# Catch PL SQL raise_exception in java

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, hibernate-entitymanager

I need to catch an exception from a procedure in PL SQL.More exactly, i need to get the message from that SQLException but the problem is that it's not entering that catch block.Instead it enters in the Exception block

userService:

```
try {
            userDao.add(user);
        }catch(SQLException se){
            System.out.println(se.getErrorCode()+" "+se.getMessage());            
        }catch (Exception e){
            //e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("\nGetCause\n"+e.getCause().toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
            //TRATARE EXCEPTII IN FUNCTIE DE ORA-20000+ code
        }
```

userDao:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
                .createStoredProcedureQuery("manage_users.add_user")
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(4, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                .registerStoredProcedureParameter(5, String.class, ParameterMode.OUT)
                .setParameter(1, user.getUsername())
                .setParameter(2, user.getPassword())
                .setParameter(3, user.getPassword())
                .setParameter(4, user.getEmail());

        query.execute();
```

In the console i get:

```
    14-May-2016 20:38:09.929 WARN [http-apr-8181-exec-45] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions SQL Error: 20001, SQLState: 72000
14-May-2016 20:38:09.930 ERROR [http-apr-8181-exec-45] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions ORA-20001: Write your username
ORA-06512: at "EDEC.MANAGE_USERS", line 65
ORA-06512: at line 1


GetCause
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
```

What is the proper way of handling those exceptions?

Comment: Are you using hibernate through JPA, or straight hibernate interfaces?

Comment: An SQLException is caught by Hibernte and is wrapped in a GenericJDBCException. You must catch GenericJDBCException instead of SQLException. Rewrite your handler in this way:  `}catch(SQLException  | GenericJDBCException  se){ ...` and your code will catch both types of exception.